# Why below interface code of TypeScript executes?

Tags: typescript

In below code snippet, I have declared a IMath interface and implemented in add method and it works, that is absolutely fine.

However, in multiply method it should have given compile error as I am only passing one parameter and the 2nd parameter is not optional.

```
interface IMath {
    (a: number, b: number): number;
}

// using the interface
var add: IMath;
add = function (a: number, b: number) {
    return a + b;
}
var sum = add(5, 3);
alert(sum);


var multiply: IMath;
multiply = function (c: number) {
    return c;
}
var result = multiply(5, 3);
alert(result);
```

But I do not get any compile error in Visual Studio, any guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because a function of type `(number) -> number` can be assigned to a type of `(number, number) -> number`. It’s just that the second argument is ignored and thrown away but that doesn’t mean that you could not call it with two arguments, making the assignment valid.

See the following minimal example that shows a valid assignment:

```
var f: (a: number, b:number) => number = function (a:number):number {
    return 0;
}
f(1, 2);
```

Comment: This is also explained in http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#type-compatibility-comparing-two-functions

Comment: Seems like I got it. I guess it is more to do with how JavaScript works, even if function with two parameters are called just with one parameter, JavaScript does it's best guess and calls the function with 2nd parameter is undefined. The same might not be possible in other programming language like C#.

Comment: Thanks a ton Poke, just updated my post referring above information - http://techfunda.com/howto/1071/interfaces-in-typescript